# ASP.net get sessionId from cookieless="UseUri"

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies, cookieless

I currently have a hosted application that needs to have a sub applications (in an iframe) authenticate.  I am currently using cookies, and have a small redirect page doing the following in a code behind.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Test User", false);
```

This sets things up later for access to the application.  Due to recent Safari changes, I am trying to get away from Cookies.  I've come across the web.config setting for cookieless="UseUri".  The hope would be that instead of setting an auth cookie, I return back passing the session (A(XXXX)S(XXXX)F(XXXX)) in the url which I will then capture and append to any followup URL requests to the sub application, but can't figure out how to generate that session id.

Comment: use `cookieless="true"` (or useUri), and your url's will automatically be formatted like this `http://localhost:54416/(S(zuh1yo5ub0jkszvivhftrpyg))/Default.aspx`. You don't have to get or set the session cookie or manipulate the URL yourself. If this is plain old Asp.Net, it will handle it. Do these app and sub apps share authentication or session?

Comment: No, they are separate.  I did find if I still used the above Set command, I could grab the session with Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(string).  Currently testing if that'll work